# Logic 9.1.1 with snow loepard OSX 10.8.2

Tags: finder

I've just bought a Mac 4 and loaded in Logic 9.1.1, all semed well until I tied to open Logic in my applications folder and it said ' I can't use this version of the application Logic pro with this version of OSX.

can anyone give me a clue?

THANKS

Comment: I'd start at http://www.apple.com/support/pro-apps and cross reverence the OS version you are running against the requirements for that version of Logic. What sort of clue are you looking for?

Comment: You should provide the Mac model and OS X version.

Answer (score 1):

Logic 9.1.1 requires Mac OS X Snow Leopard 10.6.8 or later with "Apple Software Installer Update 1.0".

Link to Apple Support
http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1519?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US